# Can not SELECT LEFT and JOIN tables with output json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried to take two characters of the id in the table by using a 'select left' and I tried to join to another table with the id parameter but does not run at the execution, and output the results in the form of json, but it does not work.

My script,

```
Controllers
        foreach($this->mymodel->getLeft()->result_array() as $row)
            {   
                $data[] = array(
                    'sub_id' => $row['sub_id'],
                    'long_id' => $row['long_id'],
                    'total' => $row['total']
                  );                
            }   
            echo json_encode($data);
```

Models:

```
function data_alat() {
    $sql = "SELECT LEFT(tb1.id,2) AS sub_id, long_id, COUNT(*) total 
            FROM tb1 JOIN tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.sub_id 
            GROUP BY sub_id ";

    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

My database:

tb1:

```
field id=
BM-001,
BM-002,
BC-009,
JK-001,
LP-080,
JK-002
```

tb2:

```
field id=
BM,
BC,
JK,
LP

field long_id=
BIM,
BIC,
JIK,
LIP
```

I expected { "sub_id": "BM", "long_id": BIM, "total": "2"}

Comment: Alias cannot be referred in same select,from,where clause of a select statement. try this instead : `SELECT
 LEFT (tb1.id, 2) AS sub_id,
 COUNT(*) total
FROM
 tb1
JOIN tb2 ON tb2.id = LEFT (tb1.id, 2)
GROUP BY
 sub_id`

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: thanks @1000111, ok the issue was ok but the results null, actually I wanted to took this data and displays it in the form of json, if no join will work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT LEFT(tb1.id,2) AS sub_id, COUNT(*) total 
            FROM tb1 LEFT JOIN tb2 on left (tb1.id,2) = tb2.sub_id 
            GROUP BY sub_id ";
```

Comment: thanks @YVS1102, yes okay to work, but how it took this long_id by id